# getType on Android

Tags: java, android, gettype

I am trying to make a program that will refresh every time the user shakes the phone and after searching on the web, I believe I have gotten one that would work and after copying it down, there seems to be only one error with getType, does anyone know what the problem might be?

[image]

Comment: Post your complete code, not an image of part of it.

Comment: What object does listofsensors contain?

Comment: usually, when dealing with objects you don't compare them with `==` but with `obj.equals(someOtherObj)`. I guess this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get the code correctly, getType() method returns an Enum, because it is equated with one. So, you need to:

```
if(something.getType().toString().equals(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER.toString()))
```

if it returns a String and is equated with a String: (but in that case you shouldn't get an error. do you get an error? you could elaborate a bit...)

```
if(something.getType().equals(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER))
```

Comment: I believe it was that I needed to make it .equal, thanks!